# Quercus Not Running in Embedded Jetty 6

Tags: java, jetty, quercus

I've been attempting to embed Jetty and Quercus in my application for the past few months, but I haven't been successful yet. I'm using Jetty version 6.1.26 and Quercus 4.0.25.

I've packaged the following jars with my application's: jetty-6.1.26.jar, jetty-util-6.1.26.jar, and servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar which I copied from the jetty/lib directory.

Here's my code that runs on its own thread:

```
public void run(){
    try{
        server = new Server(Plugin.port);

        WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
        wac.setWar(Plugin.resourceBase);
        wac.setDescriptor(Plugin.resourceBase + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
        wac.setContextPath("/");
        wac.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(wac);

        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        server.start();

        Plugin.instance.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Started web server at port " + Plugin.port);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Plugin.instance.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot start web server at port " + Plugin.port + "!");
        Plugin.instance.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the resource base directory, I have a WEB-INF folder that contains a web.xml file as well as Quercus' WEB-INF/lib and /licenses. The jars that are in the lib folder are cdi-16.jar, javaee-16.jar, javamail-141.jar, and resin.jar.

The web.xml has the following under its web app tags:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>license-directory</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/licenses</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I start the program, I get this message in the console:

10:31:46 [SEVERE] 2013-03-03 10:31:46.570:INFO:/:Unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

I can then access HTML files on the Jetty server, but when I try to access PHP ones, I get a message saying

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:243)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at me.jsn_man.WebServer.WebServer.run(WebServer.java:52)
```

If anyone can offer help that would be much appreciated.

Also, if you have suggestions of what versions of Jetty and Quercus I should be using, that would also be helpful. I'm only using Jetty 6 because that's the version which had the most documentation about embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did the same.

- Jetty 6.1.26
- Quercus from here http://caucho.com/download/quercus-4.0.25.war

I then extract the war to a folder *quercus* in the current working directory without any modifications.

Setup in embedded Jetty like this:

```
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar("./quercus");

    server.setHandler(webapp);
```

Comment: No, that didn't work either. How did you package the Jetty jars when compiling? I just copied their files into one jar and added that as a build path in eclipse, then copied that into the final program's jar.

Comment: I'm on Netbeans. All jars are in a lib folder. Seems to be a class loading problem. What is `Plugin.resourceBase` ?

Comment: Maybe google for that message: `javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class what.ever.Class is not a javax.servlet.Servlet`

Comment: I've been googling that exception for months now, finding no answers. Plugin.resourceBase is basically a string that's by default "./plugins/WebServer/web/" but can be changed by the user. I'll try not packaging the jars together for compiling and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing javaee-16.jar from the Quercus war.  I'll remove it from future Quercus distributions.  Thanks.